# What will the appropriate regex for this pattern?

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I'm pretty new to regex. The pattern I'm trying to match is something along the lines of this:

```
    A= "SOME_VALUE"
    X = 'SOME_OTHER_VALUE'
L = "HERES_ANOTHER_VALUE"            # yes, there are some instances of non-indentation 
    c = {
        D = "E",
        F='G',
        H = "I"

    }
    Q = "A VALUE WITH SPACES"
    V='VALUE_WITH_KEY_V'
```

I've done some 'playing around' on regex101, and the pattern I've come up with is the following:

`[\s]*?([\w]+)[\s]*?\=[\s]*?([\'\"\,\{\w\s\}]+)[\n]+`

[image: The output on regex101]

I want to capture the sub-class as one whole value. However, as you can see from the output, I'm not getting the desired result. Also, it would be great if I could capture the entire sub-class as an optional group. But I don't know how to do that.

What would be the most efficient regex for the aforementioned pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like so should work: `\w+\s*=\s*((\{.*?\})|(['"].*?['"]))` (note that this requires the usage of the `.DOTALL` flag to allow the `.` to match new lines, which is useful when you are dealing with classes.

An example of the expression is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/cH4Q4B/2).

Comment: Works well. Thanks a lot! Quick follow up question - how do I activate the .DOTALL flag in python?

Comment: @RahulKulhalli `re.findall(pattern, string, re.DOTALL)`